# How do I list all the files in a directory and subdirectories in reverse chronological order?

Tags: unix, find, ls

I want to do something like `ls -t` but also have the files in subdirectories included. But the problem is that I don't want the output formated like `ls -R` does, which is like this:

```
[test]$ ls -Rt
b       testdir test

./testdir:
a
```

I want it to be formatted like the `find` command displays files in subdirectories. I.e:

```
[test]$ find .
.
./b
./test
./testdir
./testdir/a
```

But what `find` doesn't seem to do is order the result chronologically by last update time.

So how can I list all the files in a directory and subdirectories, in the format that `find` does, but in reverse chronological order?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, use http://www.superuser.com and http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm using the output of this command in a program. Isn't that programming?

Comment: lowercase r? `ls -tr`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try this one:

```
find . -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -nr | cut -d\  -f2-
```

Comment: Just FYI, this only works with GNU's find. Well, at least, the find on FreeBSD doesn't support the printf command.

Comment: Isn't `find . -type f -printf "%p\n"` enough?

Comment: @TelmoTrooper not if you want the sorting. The extra character count goes into sorting by last modification time. If you do not care about this sorting, your version is enough.

Answer (score 157):

`ls -lR` is to display all files, directories and sub directories of the current directory
`ls -lR | more` is used to show all the files in a flow.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how come that this lists stuff in home directory? Flag "R" is for listing subdirectories recursively, I see no reference to home directory in ls man page. As I got it, it is listing subdirectories wherever you are.

Comment: Good and direct answer :)

Answer (score 27):

If the number of files you want to view fits within the maximum argument limit you can use globbing to get what you want, with recursion if you have globstar support.

For exactly 2 layers deep use: `ls -d * */*`

With globstar, for recursion use: `ls -d **/*`

The `-d` argument to `ls` tells it not to recurse directories passed as arguments (since you are using the shell globbing to do the recursion).  This prevents `ls` using its recursion formatting.

Comment: @YoYo Thank you for removing my redundant explanation line at the bottom.  I attempted to submit an edit with the single-character change, but it was rejected by SO for being too small of a change.  Do you know if there is a way around this?

Answer (score 8):

Try
`find . -type d`
or
`find . -type d -ls`

Comment: Can you add more explanation as to why this answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t
```

Drawback: Works only to a certain amount of files. If you have extremly large amounts of files you need something more complicated

Comment: you missed to add the search domian: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t` but then your solution works on mac os unlike the others listed here

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
ls -ltraR |egrep -v '\.$|\.\.|\.:|\.\/|total' |sed '/^$/d'
```

Answer (score 1):

The command in [wfg5475's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16362635/4320665) is working properly, just need to add one thing to show only files in a directory & sub directory:

```
ls -ltraR |egrep -v '\.$|\.\.|\.:|\.\/|total|^d' |sed '/^$/d'
```

Added one thing: `^d` to ignore the all directories from the listing outputs

Answer (score 0):

If its ok to use GUI, try `nautilus .` and then search from the search bar. By default, this search lists all the files in directory and subdirectories. However, sorting in reverse chronological order is not possible.